# Path to image in Django Template for emails not work

Tags: html, django, templates

I want to add the images to my html template for the emails. In my project settings i have

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

and

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
...
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

in my url i have

```
urlpatterns = [


] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

my project structure

[image]

my email method

```
message = render_to_string('recovery_password.html', {
            "code": code,
            "MEDIA_URL": settings.MEDIA_URL
        })
        mail_subject = 'Recovery password'

        email = EmailMessage(mail_subject,
                             message,
                             to=[to_email],
                             )
        email.content_subtype = "html"
        email.send()
```

and in the recovery_password.html i have link on the image

```
<a><img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}image1.png/></a>
```

But my image in the email not work. It doesnt display in the temlate

**UPD: My all structure of project**
[image]

Comment: It's a little hard to tell when you obscure your directory structure like that. All I can see is you've configured the directory as "templates" and named it as "media". But there's also a sub dir there. Convention says store your templates as <app>/<template>/<app>/template1..n.html to avoid confusion in the event 2 apps use the same template name.

Comment: @urbanespaceman thanks for comment. I have a separate folder with templates and separate forlder with images. Plase see my UPD question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use full path to the image including your domain name. Something like this:

```
<img src="http://example.com{{MEDIA_URL}}image1.png">
```

---

Or you can configure the domain in your settings instead of hardcoding it and then pass the domain variable to the `render_to_string` context:

```
# settings.py
DOMAIN = 'http://www.example.com'

################

message = render_to_string('recovery_password.html', {
        "code": code,
        "MEDIA_URL": settings.MEDIA_URL,
        "DOMAIN": settings.DOMAIN,
    })
```

Then in your template:

```
<img src="{{DOMAIN}}{{MEDIA_URL}}image1.png">
```